# Multiple graphs with r

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two datasets that have exactly the same columns and exactly the same products, but the first table contains the Forecast and the second one contains the actual sales.

I would like to create for each product a WoW line graph showing one line for sales and one line in another color for the FC. I am building an rmd html file and would like to have in this case 4 graphs on the page.
Unfortunately I don't have only 4 products in real life and I cannot write a code for every product.

Is there a way to make out of these two table four (or more) plots with WoW FC and Sales lines with a simple code?

Thank you!

Forecast:

| Product | CW1 | CW2 | CW3 | CW4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 9 | 12 | 21 | 8 |
| B | 7 | 5 | 6 | 9 |
| C | 10 | 10 | 20 | 15 |
| D | 10 | 9 | 8 | 8 |

Actual sales:

| Product | CW1 | CW2 | CW3 | CW4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 11 | 21 | 7 |
| B | 10 | 5 | 7 | 9 |
| C | 9 | 10 | 21 | 15 |
| D | 10 | 10 | 9 | 8 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be best to bind your two data frames row-wise (after labelling each with a column to declare which original data frame it was in), then pivot them into long format so that all the CW values are in a single column, with a new column to label which "CW" they came from. This new data frame will contain all the information you need to create a simple line plot in `ggplot2`

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

bind_rows(list(sales = sales, forecast = forecast), .id = "type") %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("CW")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(name, value, color = type, group = type)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_discrete(name = "") +
  facet_wrap(.~Product, ncol = 2)
```

[image]

---

**Data**

```r
forecast <- structure(list(Product = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), CW1 = c(9L, 7L, 
10L, 10L), CW2 = c(12L, 5L, 10L, 9L), CW3 = c(21L, 6L, 20L, 8L
), CW4 = c(8L, 9L, 15L, 8L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

sales <- structure(list(Product = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), CW1 = c(10L, 
10L, 9L, 10L), CW2 = c(11L, 5L, 10L, 10L), CW3 = c(21L, 7L, 21L, 
9L), CW4 = c(7L, 9L, 15L, 8L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

forecast
#>   Product CW1 CW2 CW3 CW4
#> 1       A   9  12  21   8
#> 2       B   7   5   6   9
#> 3       C  10  10  20  15
#> 4       D  10   9   8   8

sales
#>   Product CW1 CW2 CW3 CW4
#> 1       A  10  11  21   7
#> 2       B  10   5   7   9
#> 3       C   9  10  21  15
#> 4       D  10  10   9   8
```

Comment: The `.id` argument to `bind_rows` simplifies the identification of the original data frame

Comment: @RichardTelford thanks. I didn't know about that parameter. That's useful.